# Laravel Model is a scope of table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I create a custom model in Laravel where Manager is a scope of users table where is_manager = 1 ?
I think it's more clear to make different models User and Manager, is it possible ?

Comment: Do you want queries on the User model to include managers and regular users, or _just_ regular users?

Comment: Just managers ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create [a global scope class](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes) like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Scopes;

use App\Models\Hotels\AbstractHotelImage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class IsManagerScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param Model   $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void
    {
        $builder->where('is_manager ', 1);

    }
}
```

Then create your manager model making it extend your user model and apply the gloabl scope in it's `booted` method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Scopes\IsManagerScope;

class Manager extends User
{

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new IsManagerScope);
    }

}
```

You could also do it inline in the model using an [Anonymous Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#anonymous-global-scopes) which is basically the same thing just without the scope being in a separate class.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it